# is it possible to make the typescript map part of the object attributes

Tags: typescript

I am defined the `MenuItem` like this to parse the server side rest api response:

```
  type MenuItem = {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    path: string;
    tree_id_path: string;
    children: MenuItem[];
  };
```

the server side return more than 4 fields, but I only want the `MenuItem` to take 4 fields. what should I do to make it work like this? Now I am using as to cast the reponse to `MenuItem` list.

```
  export async function roleMenuTree(options?: { [key: string]: any }) {
    let response = await request<API.ApiResponse>('/manage/permission/role/v1/role/menu', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({}),
      ...(options || {}),
    });
    let dataList = response.result as API.MenuItem[];
    return dataList;
  }
```

Comment: Do you need to actually remove the extra properties from the object? Or just have typescript assume the properties don't exist and thus give you an error if you try to access them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to restrict TypeScript object to contain only properties defined by its class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49580725/is-it-possible-to-restrict-typescript-object-to-contain-only-properties-defined)

Comment: also: [TypeScript : avoid extra properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61960321/typescript-avoid-extra-properties)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this using es6.

By using the [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
let { unWantedFields ,...rest} = response.result;
let result = rest
```

Or you can use [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment?retiredLocale=he) to include your desire props

```
let {id, name, path} = response.result;
let result = {id, name, path}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can return a new object

```
export async function roleMenuTree(options?: { [key: string]: any }) {
    let response = await request<API.ApiResponse>('/manage/permission/role/v1/role/menu', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({}),
      ...(options || {}),
    });
    let newResult: MenuItem = {
      id: response?.result?.id,
      name: response?.result?.name,
      path: response?.result?.path,
      tree_id_path: response?.result?.tree_id_path,
      children: //Here your MenuItem[]
    }
    let dataList = newResult;
    return dataList;
  }
```

Or you can use this approach (If you have same names in api response as well)

```
   let {id, name, path, tree_id_path, children} = response.result;
```