# Inferred type gives error while specific type won't for extra property

Tags: typescript

Taking an example :

```
interface A {
  name  : string;
  gender: string;
}

interface B {
  name   : string;
  gender : string;
  country: string;
}

function printUser(user: A) {
  console.log(user);
}


//  this works fine
const user: B = { name: 'John', gender: 'male', country: 'USA' };
printUser(user);

// But this gives error
printUser({ name: 'John', gender: 'male', country: 'USA' });
```

Why are inferred types with extra properties not valid, but passing a known type of same value is allowed.

Comment: It's not about the type being inferred - that object literal is _only_ accessible via the A interface, so any "excess properties" cannot be accessed and are an error. But a B is also a valid A, and might be used elsewhere _as a B_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript : avoid extra properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61960321/typescript-avoid-extra-properties)