# Type not being inferred correctly in conditional operator that calls a function with a union return type

Tags: typescript

Typescript is not correctly inferring the return type of a function that's being called conditionally.

Consider the following code:

```
type Row = { row: number };
type RowAndColumn = { row: number, column: number }

function getThing(input: number): RowAndColumn | Row | null {
    if (input < 0.3) return null;
    if (input < 0.5) return { row: 0 };
    return { row: 0, column: 0 };
}
const rand = Math.random();
const input = Math.random();

const thing = (rand > 0.5 && getThing(input)) || 'hi'; // why does this type not contain RowAndColumn?
const thing2 = (rand > 0.5 && getThing(input)) ?? 'hi'; // why does this type not contain RowAndColumn?
const thing3 = rand > 0.5 ? getThing(input) : 'hi'; // why does this type not contain RowAndColumn?
const thing4 = rand > 0.5 ? getThing(input) : getThing(input) ; // why does this type not contain RowAndColumn?

const correct = getThing(input); // this is correct
const correct2 = rand > 0.5 && getThing(input); // this is correct
```

Typescript is saying that the type of the `thing` variable is `Row | "hi"`, when in reality it should be `Row | RowAndColumn | "hi"`.

Same issue with the other 3 cases. What's going on here?

Here's a link to the code in Typescript playground: [Typescript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gdygXigbygJ0QLigOwFcBbAIwkygF8BuAKFElkQEF8ATAYTgBsT8U6LLgIlymADRQAxr354iZCtTp0AZoXzTgASzgCA5hGAAVABY78BgBSWwhYArEUAlHngI2XOcQEAfZiQAoh4edDooSKgdNShbfHtgKAAeKAAGADoAZhcsY0JMARCeeijo2PjElPSMgFZczHzCoWwEPDTqUqjG4AKBDFb2qVk%20X3bOuio6WXwAZyTMAEMOQQBZReAzDKWOOGJrF3oZ%20eiEhzWNrZ32PYP6af0TzcsDQWtrqAA%20GtqoADI-lAjKYLFZKg4XLk-AEAOQWGE0KAAeiRUAQZhAUBuEFmUGeuMY0HwcCSM2Ai0sgS83FG%20AA-A85klnlYAExvD7fTK-AFA4zmF7g4CQqB0ulQOE6BHI1HozHYgkWAngIkkmT6cmUjzUnz0xlPUEGLKCTk-UV8kGCuwQqB4SXSlFojFYuA4vFKvEqghqskUgTajg0-gM47Mw0AFhNy3YXzN4uBArB1uFtotiZsydyiMdcpdbvxnqYxNJGr9VMDuoZ%20pLmEa2kECcNQsOMvdOlx7fVtYg2mrXbrwHZqFN3P%20gMbVrOwuzqILndk3e0QA)

Comment: My assupmtion is it has to do with two things: 1. TypeScript is not really distributing its Control flow analysis over unions, especially not with conditionals. 2. TypeScript types [not being exact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61960321/avoid-extra-properties). I tried to break down your example as much as possible. Check out this [playground](https://tsplay.dev/mb1J3N).

Comment: This is known as "subtype reduction" and it happens in some situations but not in others.  See the linked questions/answers above, and GitHub issues like [ms/TS#44479](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44479).  Technically speaking, every `RowAndColumn` is also a `Row`, so `Row | RowAndColumn` is equivalent to `Row`.  Whether or not the compiler chooses to explicitly make such a reduction is an implementation detail of the language.