# "has no properties in common with type" error on only partial interface

Tags: typescript

I get compile error for the following code:

```
type OnlyPartial={
    foo?:{
        bar1?:string
    }
}

interface Product1<T extends OnlyPartial >{
    productInfo?:T
}

const temp1 = {
        foo:{
            'bar0':'bar0'
        }
    }

//Type '{ foo: { bar0: string; }; }' does not satisfy the constraint 'OnlyPartial'.
//  Types of property 'foo' are incompatible.
//    Type '{ bar0: string; }' has no properties in common with type '{ bar1?: string | undefined; }'.(2344)
const product1:Product1<typeof temp1> = {
    productInfo:temp1
}
```

and there's no error for the following code

```
type NotOnlyPartial={
    foo?:{
        bar1?:string
        bar2:string
    }
}

interface Product2<T extends NotOnlyPartial>{
    productInfo?:T
}

const temp2 ={foo:{
            'bar2':'bar2',
            'bar0':'bar0'
        }}

const product2:Product2<typeof temp2> = {
    productInfo:temp2
}
```

The second example is obvious. 'bar1' is optional so there's no need to be 'bar1' in `productInfo.foo`. But on the first example, `bar1` is also optional but error message says that `bar1` is needed in `productInfo`.

What's the difference? How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have encountered an issue with [TypeScript types not being exact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61960321/avoid-extra-properties). In your first example `OnlyPartial.foo` and `temp1.foo` have no properties in common. However, in your second example there is a common property `bar2`. That means `temp2` is actually considered a [*subtype*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#subtype-vs-assignment) of `NotOnlyPartial`.

So, the problem in example1 is not that `bar1` is missing but that `bar0` is there additionally.

Check out this example:

```
type OnlyPartial = {
  bar1?: string;
};

const toAssign = {
  bar0: "bar0", // <- remove this property or add it to "OnlyPartial"
};

const onlyPartial: OnlyPartial = toAssign;
//    ~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type '{ bar0: string; }' has no properties in common with type 'OnlyPartial'.

type NotOnlyPartial = {
  bar1?: string;
  bar2: string;
};

const toAssign2 = {
  bar2: "bar2",
  bar0: "bar0",
};

const notOnlyPartial = toAssign2;
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gdgGxABQIYCdgEtUKgXigG8AoKKAIwwEYB%20ALigGdh0s4BzAbhIF8eSAYwD2cFlGDCAgkyZYOcAsTKUMABkYAiKujWaANHwEixwKKKRpMOBI3iWM2XEsky5CngHpP5cgD8AwKC-Em8oABVwaAByIlVdRhY2Ti4oXmioAAtUJig4YSgwdGFIawhc9igRAFtq0SgAdyxgTIkoqGj7FEcbaIA6EhJQSCgAOWFgLqsnPEJSch06RNZ2bhUdACZl5LX%20QZNxV1l5OA2lefitqG0MDYN19S0dPUM9oVFxfMnEbutnQiO7lOPCAA)