# Why don't I get a type error when I do a type-unsafe assignment in typescript?

Tags: typescript, type-conversion, typeerror

here is the test code:

```
const a = {p1: 1, p2: 2} as const;


/**
 * reassign, there is not type error
 */
const b: {[k: symbol]: string} = a;


/**
 * write literal object directly, it occurs type error
 */
const c: {[k: symbol]: string} = {p1: 1, p2: 2} as const;
```

here is the playground link: [playgound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA3gBwIwC4YYDQxoBMORAvvBDKJFANwBQTA9AFSsMyswBOApnAgQAlgHMwBKAAs%20-GMKpgQsKAE80fGLJ4genVswY1oMAEY4UAbQDWOCKoC2pkABsAunag9hYURWRwjCzs%20jAA7t5Qmi7CUTxwLjAgpgBWfMCwACbC-BkuqgSxScDAAK48VGoaWjw6elyGxrDAFjZ2js7unt6%20-qiYOPiEJDDklNTg0IxAA)

Comment: This is because [TypeScript types are not exact](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936). Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61960321/avoid-extra-properties.