# TypeScript does not validate the type in objects with optional keys

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```js
type EventFilters = "gte" | "gt" | "lte" | "lt" | "eq" | "neq";

type startDateType = {
    [key in EventFilters]?: string;
};

function test(startDate: startDateType) {
    console.log(startDate)
}
```

```js
test({"gte": "off", "invalidkey": "123"});
```

This code throws the following error:

```js
Argument of type '{ gte: string; invalidkey: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'startDateType'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and '"invalidkey"' does not exist in type 'startDateType'
```

And that's correct because "invalidkey" is not a valid key.

But in this case, TypeScript does not throw any type of error

```js
const props = {"gte": "off", "invalidkey": "123"};
test(props);
```

I know that if I assign a type to the props variable, it will throw an error. But what I'm looking for is for the function to throw an error indicating that the type is invalid.

Example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ts=5.2.2&ssl=13&ssc=13&pln=12&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsAYgSwDbAgJwM5QC8UARAObYlQA+pFVtJWEDpWrJEAjh4tyQG4AUENCQoeYAEMcwACJTsAFXDRiAbyFRtOgNoBrCCChpEsBMnTN8AXQD8ALgnAcpssJ1QAvsJEAzAFdEAGNgNAB7M2xJAApJGXlFCCd42QVlVQBKKE1PYMi8cIwIADoMcLI46TSkzKEvEXzESSgwHHCwAg1ySicScL8-EgAaUlM4KQw0ABNDEBI+gEYAJgBmEh9RCFi2jrxM32jgGPUelj6BodGSccmZuYXSFfWvA6A

Comment: You're looking for *exact* types. Check out this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsAYgSwDbAgJwM5QC8UARAObYlQA+pFVtJWEDpWrJEAjh4tyQG4AUENCQoAZWABDHMAAi07ABVw0YgG8hUKAG0A1hBBQ0iWAmTpm+ALoB+AFxQ8wHKbLCAvsNFrYAD2kAY2AAHgBBABooACEAPiIocKgIf2xEABMCGKg7KAAKHNT0rKTcsqc+BBwASihKiGqfADMAV0QQtAB7M2wXUOU4-JdZBSUIJxhAkIHoqVHFFTU4uq0dIJ68LowIADoMLrJhmTlFiBqvEQ3EFygwHC6wAk0oCgnSLubmkmjTOGkMGgMoYQE4SABGABMAGYqN5RBAXPl7o88BchEA). I will mark this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61960321/avoid-extra-properties