Why is my complex generic type allowing any property, weakening type safety?
I'm working on a React component with TypeScript and I'm trying to create a flexible, yet type-safe prop interface. However, I'm concerned that my current implementation might be too permissive. Here's my type definition:
type CustomComponentPropsBase<Component extends ElementType> = {
  size?: Size;
} & ComponentPropsWithoutRef<Component>;

type CustomComponentPropsWithoutChildren = {
  asChild?: false;
  children?: never;
};

type CustomComponentPropsWithChildren = {
  asChild: true;
  children: ReactElement;
};

type CustomComponentProps<Component extends ElementType> = CustomComponentPropsBase<Component> &
  (CustomComponentPropsWithoutChildren | CustomComponentPropsWithChildren);

export default function CustomComponent<Component extends ElementType = "div">({
  size = "default",
  asChild = false,
  children,
  ...props
}: CustomComponentProps<Component>): JSX.Element {
  // Component implementation
}

My intention was to create a component that:

Can be rendered as different HTML elements or React components
Has a size prop
Either doesn't allow children (asChild: false) or requires a single child element (asChild: true)
Allows all props of the underlying component (via ComponentPropsWithoutRef), including the default "div" if no children is passed

However, I'm worried that this type definition might be too permissive and allow any property to be passed to the component, weakening the type safety as I can just access props.whatever without raising any type issue.

Please edit your post to show an usage-example of your types.

Questions about TypeScript types are usually better when accompanied by links to the TypeScript Playground with the types involved.

It would be very helpful if you could [edit] to provide a self-contained [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE that demonstrates your issue.  That way we could get right to work on finding a solution instead of having to spend effort on seeing the problem in the first place.  Right now I just get all kinds of errors unrelated to your question.

There are two main things to address:
Dependent properties - asChild and children
Using a union of both possible types works in enforcing their relationship, but:

You don't get the benefit of adapting type hinting when passing/defining the value.

As in, regardless of how you set asChild, the type hinting for children will be the union of its type among the outer union. So in your case ReactElement | undefined | never ==> ReactElement | undefined


TS errors will show up on the whole object since the object as it is, can't be assigned to either type in the union. It'd be better to have the error on the incorrectly defined property.

The solution: Use generic types and functions
With generics you can make one property's type depend on the generic type which can be inferred from another property.
// Simplified example
type CustomComponentProps<WithChildren extends boolean> = {
  asChild: WithChildren,
} & (WithChildren extends true ? {children: ReacElement} : {children?: never})

Note: The reason this is an object intersection instead of just conditionally assigning the type of children with WithChildren is tat we can't make a property optional with conditional types. Even a union with undefined will require you to pass the prop with a value of undefined.
Limiting Props
Props not in the defined types will be caught by the compiler when being passed separately, so if that's your main use case, have no fear:
type Props = {
    a: string
}

function Component(props: Props) {
    return <div>Hello world</div>
};

function Main() {
    return <Component a="foo" b="bar" /> // Error - property 'b' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'
}

Playground
But if you're passing/spreading an object, then TS will allow it as long as the object's type is covariant on (structurally derived from) the prop's type.
import React from 'react';

type Props = {
    a: string
}

function Component(props: Props) {
    return <div>Hello world</div>
};

const props = {
    a: 'foo',
    b: 123
}

function Main() {
    return <Component {...props} /> // No error
}

Playground
Semi-solution: If you really want to play it safe, try to avoid spreading objects, but of course there are cases where it's just not feasible. Even in those cases, I truly wouldn't worry too much about it if I were you, but if you really want to limit it, you can check out the approaches here and here. These approaches need the function to be generic so they add a bit of bulk at every component definition, so it's ultimately up to you to decide if it's worth it. Here's an example using the type from the first answer:
import React from 'react';

type Props = {
    a: string
}

// From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61960321/avoid-extra-properties
type Exact<A, B> = A extends B
  ? B extends A
    ? A
    : never
  : never

function Component<T extends Props>(props: Exact<T, Props>) {
    return <div>Hello world</div>
};

const props = {
    a: 'foo',
    b: 123
}

function Main() {
    return <Component {...props} /> // Error: Type '{ a: string; b: number; }' is not assignable to type 'never'
}

Playground
