Is there a TS mode where undefined fields are allowed but have type `unknown`?
The following code seems to pass TS's typechecks despite being wrong
type Foo = {
  foo: 'foo'
}

type Bar = {
  bar: 'bar'
}

type FooOrBar = Foo | Bar

function isFoo(o: FooOrBar) {
  if ('foo' in o) {
    return o
  } else {
    throw new Error('Only "foo"s please!')
  }
}

const fooledYou = {
  bar: 'bar',
  foo: 'fooled you!'
} as const

const test: FooOrBar = fooledYou

const huh: Foo = isFoo(test)

console.log(huh.foo) // 'fooled you!'


It is my understanding, that TS is treating Bar as a type that has no other fields besides for bar, hence the check if ('foo' in o) would narrow o to Foo. But in reality Bar can have any amount of { [keyof any]: unknown }.
Should/does TS have a mode where
type Bar = { bar: 'bar' }

is treated as:
type Bar = {
  foo: 'bar'
  [key: keyof any]: unknown
}

This better reflects the reality and would prevent the above example from passing type checking.

Please [edit] to clearly ask a specific question. Right now I can't tell if it's the question in the title, or some implication of the body text. • If it's as the title asks, no: there is no such mode that allows you to access unknown properties in an object type, although TS does often give such indexed types unknown or any. • If it's something about the in operator narrowing being "wrong", it is known to be unsound although few people make such errors in real life.

(see prev comment) • If it's about your index signature change, it doesn't narrow because foo can't discriminate between Foo and Bar... I could go on but I'm not sure which to focus and expand upon.

Thanks. I'm sorry I came across as rambling. My main question was if TS has a sounder mode that prevents code such as the example from compiling. My thought process was that were TS to "realize" that {foo:string} can contain any number of other {[keyof any]:unknown}, then the narrowing would not work, preventing the wrong code from compiling. Therefore I was asking if there were such a mode. My last point was not part of the question, just a something I noticed and haven't yet understood, that explicitly adding {[keyof any]:unknown} had left me with no way to narrow based on runtime check

Concerning your second comment: If it's about your index signature change, it doesn't narrow because foo can't discriminate between Foo and Bar. That's something that trips me up often: I keep mischaracterizing type "narrowing" as type "asserting". i.e. whereas o.foo === 'foo' can prove that o is assignable to Foo it can't discriminate in a union of Foo and Bar

@jcalz, I have edited my question to be more focused. I suppose you have already answered it in the comments

Maybe a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61960321/avoid-extra-properties ?

I still don't quite get it. TS mostly does treat types as if extra properties of type unknown (well, usually any) might exist. But even if there were a "mode" that made this more explicit, it wouldn't change the problem you're having in your example code, which is that in operator narrowing is unsound. Maybe it's an XY problem: you don't like in unsoundness, so you think some kind of compiler option involving extra properties would help (but it wouldn't). How to proceed here?
